# c++ what actually gets copied when I assign an array to another

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to understand what happens in C++ when I assign one array pointer the value of another. Say I have:

```
int *a = new int[10];
int *b = new int[10];

for (int i =0; i< 10; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
}

b=a;
```

When I print out the values of `b` I get the same values as `a`. Makes sense. But what is actually getting saved in the `b` pointer? Is it the memory address of array `a`? I tried printing out `&a` and `&b` but I get two different values. Then how is `b` getting all the values of `a`?

Also if they are stored seperately would/should I be deleting `a` after the transfer? `delete [] a`

Thanks I'm pretty new to C++ any help would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you don't assign one array to another, you assing one *pointer* to another pointer. If that alone doesn't make it easier to understand what's happening, then continue to read...

When you do

```
int *a = new int[10];
int *b = new int[10];
```

you will have something like this:

```
+---+      +------------------------+
| a | ---> | Memory allocated for a |
+---+      +------------------------+

+---+      +------------------------+
| b | ---> | Memory allocated for b |
+---+      +------------------------+
```

After the assignment

```
b = a;
```

It instead looks like this

```
+---+      +------------------------+
| a | -+-> | Memory allocated for a |
+---+  |   +------------------------+
       |
+---+  |   +------------------------+
| b | -/   | Memory allocated for b |
+---+      +------------------------+
```

In other words, `b` points to the same memory as `a`, nothing points to the memory originally allocated for `b` so it is inaccessible, and you will have a *memory leak*.

Furthermore, trying to do

```
delete[] a;
delete[] b;
```

will lead to *undefined behavior* as you try to free the same memory twice.

Comment: these diagrams are beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

You are just assigning a pointer to the array. So `b` will point to the same address of `a`.

You get 2 different address because you are printing the address of the pointer itself not the address stored in the pointer.

```
&a != &b  //the addresses of the pointer variables are different
a == b  // the address stored in the pointers is the same
```

> But what is actually getting saved in the b pointer? Is it the memory
>   address of array a.

It's the memory address stored into the `a` pointer.

> Also if they are stored seperately would/should I be deleting a after
>   the transfer? delete [] a

If you delete memory pointed by `a`, `b` will point to a de-allocated memory region.

Comment: then why is it when I print `&a` and `&b` I get `0x61ff0c` and `0x614408`? Should they not be the same?

Comment: @johnmurphy: If I write my home address on two post-it notes, they say the same thing but they're still separate post-it notes, and I can stick them in different places around my house.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by doing `b=a` you have a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You are copying the address of the first value of array a (lets say that `&(a[0]) == a`) to variable b and as a result you completely lose control of the address of the first value of array b. You should always call `delete` operator first before doing such an action.

Have in mind that a pointer variable always stores an address but because it's a variable as well it also has its own address. As a result, in a variable/pointer is stored the address of the first value of array a so if you print a you get that address. if you print `&a`, you get the address of the variable/pointer `a` which is useless for you in this example.

To get a better idea imagine that an array is a branch of continuous variables stored in memory and you access them by always knowing only the address of the first value of these continuous variables. So, when you say `a[0]` it's exactly like saying "*get me the content of the value of the first variable of the array*" and then when you say `a[1]` it is exactly like asking for the value of the variable which is located at the address of `a[0]` plus the exact next variable stored in memory next to `a[0]` which is variable `a[1]` and is also equal to `*(a+1)`. (yes, `*(a+1)` is equal to `a[1]` and so on)

Also, try to read a bit about operations among pointers. For example, and `addressA + 1` is equal to the next address stored in memory (from address A).

Last but not least, in order to get a better idea about these staff, print the values and addresses of the pointers and play with them (solve some easy exercises with arrays and pointers).

Comment: `free()` is for C-based allocation. As the memory was allocated with C++'s `new`, is should be deallocated with C++'s `delete`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I have corrected it thanks! ;)
And `delete` is actually an operator, not a function ;)

Answer (score 0):

As `b` is a pointer to an int, assigning anything to it will be assigning the memory address of an int only. Essentially arrays are nothing but pointer arithmetic at its core, and they work by moving over to the next memory address by a specific number of bytes based on the element byte size. Thus when it comes to arrays, you'll have pointers or pointers to pointers which ultimately point at an `int` or some other data type like a `char`. Then in order to move to the next element of the array, you simply add `sizeof(int)` to the pointer address to get the next element of the array. But with pointer arithmetic, as C/C++ already knows the byte structure of the data type the pointer points to. Using `++` or `--` in the context of pointers means move forwards or backwards to the next element of the array.

When you assign `b = a`, as both are pointer to ints, you're just assigning the address of the first element of your initial allocated memory stored in `a` to `b`. Thus losing a reference to your second 10 ints of allocated memory. And since you lose a reference to the allocated memory, this will result in a memory leak as there's no reference to it to `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to program by C++, you must use C++ way. So use STL container. Most simple and useful container is [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> a(10);
std::vector<int> b(10);

for (int i =0; i< a.size(); i++) {
   a[i] = i;
}
b=a; //it works!!!
assert(a==b);
```

There is not any need to use any delete operator with vector.